# Cookieless sessions not working in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am unable to use cookieless sessions in [SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint). Everytime when I click on a site or subsite a new session id is getting created which is not as per expected behaviour (it is visible in the URL). How can I use cookieless sessions in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Shared Services Provider.  This is required in order to enable Session State and its content database is the location of our session data.  If you already have an SSP, you can use the existing one.
2. If needed, associate your web application with this SSP (done by default if it is your first SSP).
3. In Central Administration, under Application Management, choose Session State, and ensure that it is enabled.
4. From a command prompt, navigate to the Microsoft.NET 2.0 Framework directory
   (typically:  C:WINDOWSMicrosoft.NETFrameworkv2.0.50727)
5. Modify your web.config:

Uncomment the following line:

```
<add name=”Session” type=”System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule” />
```

Modify the following line:

```
<pages enableSessionState=”true” … />
```

1. Run the following command:

   aspnet_regsql.exe -S    -d    -ssadd  -sstype c  -E

where:

```
<server_name>  is the database server where your database is located
<database_name>  is the content database of your shared services provider
```

Run aspnet_regsql.exe /?  for more information on the remaining options

Comment: From the steps that you have mentioned above I can see that you have given the steps as to how to use SQL server session state in MOSS. I want to use InProc session and that too cookieless. Thats where I am facing the issue....

Comment: checked that the server is not setup as a web farm or garden if not please paste your web.config enteries

Comment: one additional question are you using load balanced servers

Comment: actually I want cookieless sessions and hence the session Ids are passed in URL just as we use in .NET but the same does not work in Sharepoint.

Comment: Is it default behaviour of Sharepoint to append a new session Id every time??